# Send email using smtp.gmail.com with 465 port from php on google cloud compute engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have Google cloud compute server instance. And i want to send email using smtp.gmail.com with port 465 using PHPMailer function. but it return error : "SMTP error: Could not authenticate."

I don't want to used any third party mail provider like Sendgrid, Mailgun, Mailjet and G Suite.

On other server like AWS we just have to enable email setting and port to send email. I don't want to integrate any 3rd party email provider.

I am new to google cloud server configuration. Please someone help me to send email using smtp.gmail.com with port 465 from google cloud compute engine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That seems more like a config issue than something from gcloud, your configuration should be ok if you look here: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/

Answer (score 0):

As documented [here,](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/#choosing_an_email_service_to_use) you will have to use a SMTP relay agent service using a GSuite domain. This is only if you do not want use the third party email providers. Using the SMTP realy agent service, you can only use port 465 or 587.

Answer (score 0):

I know your question was asked in February of 2019, but I came across it and wanted to give more information for those who may find your question.

PHP is great for sending email because it is fast. PHP mail settings are configured in your PHP.ini file and most issues with it can be resolved via some setting in there. Google cloud has ports 465 (ssl) and 587 (tls) open for you to use. In fact, only port 25 is closed. You specified you were using 465, so you are good to go there. The issue is that you are trying to use Google's SMTP system and likely have not set up the proper configuration - hence the system cannot authenticate you. PHP just creates the message and hands it off to the system to send. The system's smptp system requires a valid login to send mail though. Remember, PHP does NOT require authentication for you to use it.

You can use POST SMTP, which is a free wordpress plugin, to help you configure things if you are using Wordpress.

Walk through this document to see what settings you may need to configure.

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/

You said you didn't want to use GSuite, but you should read through the documentation for the setup so you can see how to configure the SMTP settings. I am including the link to read the document because email on Google Compute Engine is not trivial and there are little things to configure here and there that you should know about.

https://www.jvfconsulting.com/blog/php-mail-function-vs-smtp-guaranteed-delivery/